# Expanding comma-separated list into separate lines

Tags: command-line, text-processing, regular-expression

I have a file with some data in this form:

```
Prefix text: First Name, Second Name, Third--
```

The prefix differs by line. The number of names varies from one to several. The suffix (`--` in the example) is optional and non-alphabetic. I need to expand the comma-separated list of names into multiple lines (easy: `s/,/\n/g`), but in such a way that prefix and suffix (if present) surround each of the new entries:

```
Prefix text: First name--
Prefix text: Second name--
Prefix text: Third--
```

Instead of banging out a too-long python script, I thought it'd be more fun to ask if someone here can think of the perfect one-liner. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -lne 'if(/^(.*?: )(.*?)(\W*)$/){print"$1$_$3"for split/, /,$2}'
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works like a charm, thanks! Right, `print X for split`.