# Expanding comma separated list in a tab-delimited file into separate lines

Tags: text-processing, command-line, regular-expression, perl, text-formatting

I have a very similar problem to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110303/expanding-comma-separated-list-into-separate-lines), but have no idea how to adapt the answer to my own issue.

I have a tab-sep file with 2nd column containing comma-sep list, such as:

```
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g1   DN1_c0_g1   GO:0000166,GO:0003674,GO:0005488,GO:0005515,GO:0005524,GO:0005575
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g3   DN1_c0_g3   GO:0005829,GO:0006457,GO:0006458,GO:0006950,GO:0008134
TRINITY_DN10_c0_g1  DN10_c0_g1  GO:0050896,GO:0051082,GO:0051084,GO:0051085
```

I want to get it to this:

```
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g1   DN1_c0_g1   GO:0000166
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g1   DN1_c0_g1   GO:0003674
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g1   DN1_c0_g1   GO:0005488
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g1   DN1_c0_g1   GO:0005515
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g1   DN1_c0_g1   GO:0005524
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g1   DN1_c0_g1   GO:0005575
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g3   DN1_c0_g3   GO:0005829
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g3   DN1_c0_g3   GO:0006457
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g3   DN1_c0_g3   GO:0006458
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g3   DN1_c0_g3   GO:0006950
TRINITY_DN1_c0_g3   DN1_c0_g3   GO:0008134
TRINITY_DN10_c0_g1  DN10_c0_g1  GO:0050896
TRINITY_DN10_c0_g1  DN10_c0_g1  GO:0051082
TRINITY_DN10_c0_g1  DN10_c0_g1  GO:0051084
TRINITY_DN10_c0_g1  DN10_c0_g1  GO:0051085
```

There is a variable number of terms in the 3rd column. I need a separate line for each with it's associated 1st and 2nd column.

If any help, the starting one liner from above questions is:

```
perl -lne 'if(/^(.*?: )(.*?)(\W*)$/){print"$1$_$3"for split/, /,$2}'
```

But I have no idea which bits needs to be changed to work for my issue!

Many thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Are you _positive_ there are tabs in your input file, and not sequences of spaces?

Comment: Can you provide us the output of the command: `cat -A yourfile` ? That will show what kind of line ndings are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awk command is quite readable:

```bsh
awk '
  BEGIN {FS = "[,\t]"; OFS = "\t"}
  {for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $2, $i}
' file
```

---

In perl, this is

```bsh
perl -F'[,\t]' -lane 'print join "\t", @F[0,1], $F[$_] for 2..$#F' file
# or
perl -F'[,\t]' -slane 'print @F[0,1], $F[$_] for 2..$#F' -- -,=$'\t' file
```

---

If you're not sure you have actual tab characters:

- awk: `FS = ",|[[:blank:]]+"`
- perl: `-F',|\s+'`

---

And for fun, bash

```bsh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    prefix=${line%%GO:*}
    IFS=, read -ra gos <<< "${line#$prefix}"
    for go in "${gos[@]}"; do echo "$prefix$go"; done
done < file
```

This version doesn't care about spaces versus tabs, but it will be *much* slower than perl or awk.

Comment: Thanks @glenn-jackman but both is giving 3 GO:xxx columns, the first two are repeats of first 2 terms in comma-sep list and 3rd is working way through rest. I need each line to only have one GO:xxx. Definitely tab-separated columns.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you except I don't believe you have tabs in the input file. I can reproduce what you're seeing with `expand file | awk ...`

Comment: Oh damn... you were right. Mi real (very big) file is tab-delim. My mocked up one to test your answers was not. My sincere apologies for wasting your time - it works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-a` switch to get each line split into the @F array on whitespace.

```
perl -lane 'print join "\t", @F[0, 1], $_ for split /,/, $F[2]'
```

Comment: Thanks for speedy reply! But this outputting nothing :(

Comment: It works for me. Did you provide the input file as the last argument?

Comment: As above, my mistake in test file I was using was not actually tab-delim. Sorry this works too!

Comment: The `-a` splits on any whitespace, tabs or spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Another option here is the `nest --explode` action of [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html)

```
mlr --nidx --fs tab nest --explode --values --across-records --nested-fs ',' -f 3 file
```

or using the shorthand `nest` specifier

```
mlr --nidx --fs tab nest --evar ',' -f 3 file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **GNU sed** which has [\n\t] regex features we can do as shown:

```
sed -n '
  y/,/\n/
  :a
      P; s/\t[^\n\t]*\n/\t/
  ta
'  file
```

---

You can do it using **perl** also

```
perl -F'(\t)' -pale '$"="";
  $_ = pop(@F) =~ tr/,/\n/r =~ s/^/@F/mgr;
' file
```

---

One method with **Perl** is shown here.
$a scalar holds the first two fields and then the search begins in the while loop from where it was left off due to the /c modifier.

```
perl -lne '
  my($a) = /^((?:.*?\t){2})/gc;
  print $a, $1 while /\G([^,]+)(?:,|$)/g;
' file
```